# PHP PDO fetchAll() vs direct foreach loop

Tags: php, pdo, fetchall

Is there any difference between these two:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM ARTICLES');
$stmt->execute();

foreach ($stmt as $article) {
    echo $article['title'];
}
```

and

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM ARTICLES');
$stmt->execute();

$articles = $stmt->fetchAll();
foreach ($articles as $article) {
    echo $article['title'];
}
```

Is there any major differences between those two methods?

EDIT: I'm just asking, because both appear to work the same for me.

Comment: yes; the first one will throw an error since you didn't fetch anything. Least, from what you posted.

Comment: Yes there's a big difference

Comment: Why not try them and see?

Comment: Thats why im asking. Cause both work the same. :(

Comment: @Fred-ii- are you sure about that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only difference is that the former [doesn't consume extra memory](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#foreach) for the returned records like the latter does.

However, given you generally shouldn't fetch more records than could be shown on a single HTML page anyway, the difference considered to be a negligible one.

Comment: Thank you so much. And thank you for that link. A lot of useful information there I can learn from :) EDIT: Will mark as answer in 7 min. ^^

Comment: Thank you whoever upvoted this answer, but I would rather prefer this upvote to go for the question instead.

Comment: So is while loop the best to itterate over results? Or does it not matter that much which one of the 3 I use?

Comment: while loop with fetch is similar to foreach. so I'd rather say it doesn't matter which one to use.